# How to validate JavaScript created element in asp.net core mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form which contain elements (checkboxes) that will be produced using JavaScript and I want to check if at least one of them is checked. Also, I have a few inputs that I want to check if at least one of them has value. The initial problem was The code I wrote displayed the error message but immediately submits the form. I can't use server side validation here because these items are created through JS. and I'm not sure if I can use server side validation to check if at least one input field has value.

For this problem I tried using `e.preventDefault();` , it stops the form from submitting if there is no value or checkbox not checked but if there was a value it will still not submit the form

This the code I tried

```
$(function () { 
                $("#SubmitForm-btn").click(function () {
                    $("#fupForm").submit(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var valid = true;
//here I'm checking if any of the input field has value.

                        $('#dataTable tbody tr td input[type=text]').each(function () {
                            var text_value = $(this).val();
                            if (!hasValue(text_value)) {
                                
                                valid = false;
                                $("#tableEmpty").html("Please Choose a Service");
                                return false;
                            }
                            else {
                                $("#fupForm").unbind('submit');
                                valid = true;
                                return true;
                                
                            }


                        })

//here I'm checking if any of the checkbox is checked.
                        $('.check').each(function () {
                            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                                valid = false;
                                $("#Person_errorMSG").html("Please choose a person");
                                return false;

                            }
                            else {
                                $("#fupForm").unbind('submit');
                                valid = true;
                                return true;
                            }

                        });

//here I'm checking if any of the checkbox is checked.
                        $('.Fromcheck').each(function () {
                            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                                valid = false;
                                $("#From_errorMSG").html("Please choose a City");
                                return false;

                            }
                            else {
                                $("#fupForm").unbind('submit');
                                valid = true;
                                return true;
                            }

                        });
//here I'm checking if any of the checkbox is checked.
                        $('.Tocheck').each(function () {
                            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                                valid = false;
                                $("#To_errorMSG").html("Please choose a To city");
                                return false;

                            }
                            else {
                                $("#fupForm").unbind('submit');
                                valid = true;
                                return true;
                            }

                        });
                    });
                    
                });
            });
```

Comment: This is a situation where I think the use of jQuery is actually hurting you a lot. This is a much simpler function without jQuery. I'm trying to mentally parse everything that's going on and it's pretty hard to follow. That said, if the form can't be submitted without at least one box checked, I think the ux best practice here is to actually disable the submit button until at least one box is checked, which would be a totally different block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent the button click event, instead of the form submit action.

Please refer the following sample code:

In the View page, we have a `mainform`.

```
    <form id="mainform" asp-action="AddAttribute">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AttributeId" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="AttributeId" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="AttributeId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
       ...
        <div class="form-group">
           Is Submit <input type="checkbox" class="isSubmit" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" id="SubmitForm-btn" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

At the end of the above page, add the following script:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#SubmitForm-btn").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault(); //prevent the default submit action.

            //check if the checkbox is checked or not.
            var ischecked = $(".isSubmit").last().is(":checked");
            if (ischecked) {
                //alert("Checked");
                //if the cleckbox checked, submit the form.
                $("#mainform").submit();
            }
            else {
                //alert("Unchecked");
                //show notification message. and the form will not submit.
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>

}
```

The result as below:

[image]